# C# JSON; Deserialize array that sometimes has an empty value (not null)

Tags: c#, arrays, json, null, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON response and I want a function that detects if the array is empty and if it is not empty I want it to return the values.

The JSON array looks like this when empty:

```
{"metrics":[]}
```

And when it is not empty it can look like any of the below:

```
{"metrics":["flow"]}

{"metrics":["energy"]}

{"metrics":["flow","energy"]}
```

How can I detect this?

It does not work with NullValueHandling since if the array is empty it is not null, it doesn't have any values at all.

I jus get an error about index is not found.

I am returning the array as a List in my classes.

Comment: You say you got an error with your code. Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Deserialize it the same way each time, then just check if your `List` is empty or not afterwards

Comment: I would think that the JSON deserializer from NewtonSoft would handle this just fine.  It would give you an array with length 0.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using Newtonsoft.Json for deserializing the json:

```
class Data
{
    public List<string> Metrics { get; set; }
}

var json = "{\"metrics\":[]}";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

`obj.Metrics` will be an *empty* collection, not null.

Plus, even if it was, you could access it like

```
var metrics = obj.Metrics ?? new List<string>();
```